# «В табачненском оркестре». С прописной буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

«В табачненском оркестре играют школьники». Речь идет о поселке Табачном в Крыму. В нем есть детский оркестр. С прописной ли буквы в данном случае или с маленькой? Какое есть правило?

Comment: Нельзя ли избежать употребления этого ужасного слова (произносящий его "сломает" язык, а читающий – глаза)? При первом упоминании написать "в оркестре поселка Табачного", во второй раз – "в поселковом оркестре".

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт об оркестре из посёлка Табачного - со строчной, как и табачненские красоты, табачненские здания, это же не название оркестра. С прописной было бы, если б оркестр носил официальное название "Табачненский".